# Perform a FFT on a Audio File

Tags: swift, fft, audio-processing, accelerate-framework

I need to perform an FFT on a sound file, more specifically a m4a file. I can do this easily using AudioKit on a audio that is playing back, but i need to perform it before hand on multiple files, is there a way we can do that, and also to do it for the entire audio file?

Does the file need to be converted into anything specific?

Comment: You might want to check out Apple's "Equalizing Audio with vDSP" sample: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/discrete_fourier_transforms/equalizing_audio_with_vdsp

Comment: @SimonGladman Thank you, lot's of gems there.